# Exclude date/time ranges from an array of date/time ranges with overlapping

Tags: php, algorithm, datetime, range, pseudocode

Hope you are doing great!!

I'm kind of stuck with this, what I've done only work when there are not overlapping and anyway am not sure it's the correct approach.

So my current implementation is to merge all times (start_time and end_time as different entry in that array), sort them and remove duplicates if any.

Then I loop into that list and check for each if they are within $times ranges and not within restrictions ranges.

All those which pass these condition are added to another list. Then finally i'll loop through that list '2 item at a time' and build the final array of time ranges.

Codes: https://3v4l.org/2elDs (Laravel, using Collection and Carbon, so won't run there)

Sample without date/time overlapping:

```
$times = [
        [
            'start_time' => '2017-06-26 00:00:00',
            'end_time' => '2017-06-26 05:00:00',
        ],
        [
            'start_time' => '2017-06-26 13:00:00',
            'end_time' => '2017-06-26 18:00:00',
        ]
    ];

$timesToExclude= [
        [
            'start_time' => '2017-06-26 04:00:00',
            'end_time' => '2017-06-26 04:30:00',
        ],
        [
            'start_time' => '2017-06-26 07:00:00',
            'end_time' => '2017-06-26 10:00:00',
        ],
        [
            'start_time' => '2017-06-26 15:00:00',
            'end_time' => '2017-06-26 16:00:00',
        ]
    ];
```

Result to:

```
    $result = [
        [
            "start_time" => "2017-06-26 00:00:00",
            "end_time"   => "2017-06-26 04:00:00"
        ], [
            "start_time" => "2017-06-26 04:30:00",
            "end_time"   => "2017-06-26 05:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "start_time" => "2017-06-26 13:00:00",
            "end_time"   => "2017-06-26 15:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "start_time" => "2017-06-26 16:00:00",
            "end_time"   => "2017-06-26 18:00:00"
        ]
    ]
```

Sample with date/time overlapping

```
    $times = [
        [
            'start_time' => '2017-06-26 00:00:00',
            'end_time'   => '2017-06-26 10:00:00',
        ],
        [
            'start_time' => '2017-06-26 05:00:00',
            'end_time'   => '2017-06-26 20:00:00',
        ]
    ];

    $timesToExclude= [
        [
            'start_time' => '2017-06-26 04:00:00',
            'end_time'   => '2017-06-26 04:30:00',
        ],
        [
            'start_time' => '2017-06-26 07:00:00',
            'end_time'   => '2017-06-26 09:00:00',
        ],
        [
            'start_time' => '2017-06-26 15:00:00',
            'end_time'   => '2017-06-26 16:00:00',
        ]
    ];
```

Should result to:

```
$result = [
        [
            "start_time" => "2017-06-26 00:00:00",
            "end_time"   => "2017-06-26 04:00:00"
        ], [
            "start_time" => "2017-06-26 04:30:00",
            "end_time"   => "2017-06-26 05:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "start_time" => "2017-06-26 05:00:00",
            "end_time"   => "2017-06-26 07:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "start_time" => "2017-06-26 09:00:00",
            "end_time"   => "2017-06-26 10:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "start_time" => "2017-06-26 10:00:00",
            "end_time"   => "2017-06-26 15:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "start_time" => "2017-06-26 16:00:00",
            "end_time"   => "2017-06-26 20:00:00"
        ]
    ]
```

Anyone knows the correct algo/pseudo to deal with that?

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense to me. I have only looked at the first one yet. Input 5 arrays, output 4. I can understand that with the duplicate you mentioned. But the times are shifted. Why? 00-05 becomes 00-04. And 04-04:30 I removed or also changed. I don't understand you input/output you need to verify or explain in a different way.

Comment: @Andreas $times is my initial list of times and $timesToExclude is the times that i need to exclude from my initial list, just renamed the variable, does that make sense?

Comment: I see what you mean now. Let me think for a while.

Comment: It's too hard to code this on the phone. So much indenting has to be done and there is no easy way to do that with the phone. This is how far I have come now https://3v4l.org/dZBto I created a flag to keep track of the end time of exclude should be new start time. But it doesn't work as supposed and as I said indenting and phone. I give up. But at least you have a basic idea of my thought

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the help! Will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create common list of pairs `{time; flag}`,  where flag is `time_start, time_end, restriction_start or restriction_end`.

Sort this list by time. In case of tie use flag as secondary key (for example, `restr_start` should go after `time_end`).

Make `$Active=0`, `$Exclude=0`

Walk through sorted list.

When you meet `time_start`, increment value of `$Active`  {1}

When you meet `time_end`, decrement value of `$Active`   {2}

When you meet `restriction_start`, increment value of `$Exclude` {3}

When you meet `restriction_end`, decrement value of `$Exclude`   {4}

Open output interval in the next cases:
     {1}: `$Active` becomes 1    and `$Exclude = 0`
     {4}: `$Exclude becomes 0` and `$Active` is non-zero

Close output interval in the next cases:
     {2} `$Active` becomes 0 and   `$Exclude = 0`
     {3} `$Exclude becomes 1` and `$Active` is non-zero

example: (don't know exact php syntax for complex conditions)

```
 case $TimeStart:
            $active = $active + 1;
            if ($active=1) and ($exclude=0)
                 $range['start_time'] = $mergedTime['time'];
            break;
 ....
  case $RestrictionEnd:
            $exclude = $exclude - 1;
            if ($exclude=0) and ($active > 0)
                 $range['start_time'] = $mergedTime['time'];
            break;
```

Comment: Hi @MBo, not sure i get the (+1 for positive, -1 for negative) thing, could you explain?

Comment: Okay, think i got the absolute thing, but not the last part 'Start output interval when $Active becomes positive, and end it otherwise (0 or negative)'

Comment: I wanted to use simplified approach with negating on `restriction***` but it will fail when restriction begins before the first `times` and in some other cases. So separate counter for  restriction and additional condition is needed. Will try to correct algorithm description.

Answer (score 1):

```
function excludeOverlaping($disponibilities,$plages) {

        if(count($disponibilities) == 0)
            return $disponibilities;
        if(count($plages) == 0)
            return $disponibilities;

                usort($disponibilities, function($a, $b)
                {
                    return strtotime($a->startDate) - strtotime($b->startDate);
                });
                usort($plages, function($a, $b)
                {
                    return strtotime($a->startDate) - strtotime($b->startDate);
                });

                for($i = 0; $i < count($disponibilities); $i++){
                    for($j=0;$j<count($plages);$j++){
                        $dispo = $disponibilities[$i];
                        if(isset($dispo->exclude)){
                            break;
                        }
                        $plage = $plages[$j]; 
                        if(strtotime($dispo->startDate)>=strtotime($plage->startDate) && strtotime($dispo->endDate)<=strtotime($plage->endDate)){
                                $disponibilities[$i]->exclude = true;

                        }else if( strtotime($dispo->startDate)<strtotime($plage->startDate) && strtotime($dispo->endDate) <= strtotime($plage->endDate) && strtotime($dispo->endDate) > strtotime($plage->startDate)){
                                 $disponibilities[$i]->endDate = $plage->startDate;
                        }else if( strtotime($dispo->startDate)>=strtotime($plage->startDate)  && strtotime($dispo->startDate)<=strtotime($plage->endDate) && strtotime($dispo->endDate) > strtotime($plage->endDate)){
                                 $disponibilities[$i]->startDate = $plage->endDate;
                        }else if( strtotime($dispo->startDate)<strtotime($plage->startDate) &&  strtotime($dispo->endDate) > strtotime($plage->endDate) ){
                              echo "[[[4]]]\n";
                                $tmp = new stdClass();
                                $tmp->startDate = $dispo->startDate;
                                $tmp->endDate = $plage->startDate;
                                $tmp2 = new stdClass();
                                $tmp2->startDate = $plage->endDate;
                                $tmp2->endDate = $dispo->endDate;
                                $disponibilities[$i]->exclude = true;
                                array_push($disponibilities,$tmp);
                                array_push($disponibilities,$tmp2);

                        } 
                    }
                }
                for($i=0;$i<count($disponibilities);$i++){
                    if(isset($disponibilities[$i]->exclude)){
                       array_splice($disponibilities,$i,1);
                       $i--;
                    }
                }
                var_dump($disponibilities);

    }

    $times = array();
    $restrictions = array();
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->startDate = '2017-06-26 00:00:00';
    $obj->endDate =  '2017-06-26 07:00:00';
    array_push($times,$obj);
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->startDate = '2017-06-26 00:00:00';
    $obj->endDate = '2017-06-26 24:00:00';
    array_push($times,$obj);


    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->startDate =  '2017-06-26 04:00:00';
    $obj->endDate = '2017-06-26 06:00:00';
    array_push($restrictions,$obj);


    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->startDate = '2017-06-26 00:00:00' ;
    $obj->endDate = '2017-06-26 01:00:00';
    array_push($restrictions,$obj);


    excludeOverlaping($times,$restrictions);
```